# Sharing Instagram Stories With Open App Link

Tags: swift, facebook, instagram

How is the way to share Instagram stories with the app link as Spotify and Netflix do? -Open with Spotify or Netflix.. Not found in the documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/sharing-to-stories/

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I just found that, it is called attribution link and only for the specified users can use that.

Comment: Can you share more information ?. What should I do to use attribution link

Comment: @Tahir do you have a reference to the documentation?

Comment: any update on this one?

Comment: Does anyone know where can one apply for this?

Comment: "and only for the specified users can use that." this does not tell us anything?

Comment: @tahir Please provide some info if you were able to solve this.

Answer (score 3):

to share an url on Instagram Stories, you need to use the `com.instagram.sharedSticker.contentURL` attribute, like:

```
"com.instagram.sharedSticker.contentURL" : "your app's applink"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but how about the App name and logo? Like this one; https://imgur.com/a/MEcthHd

Comment: you can share the following contents:
- sticker
- background assets
- combination of the above
In your case the App name and logo have to be added to the sticker, so you need to create an image, which contains your App name and logo, and share it as sticker.

Comment: @BoygeniusDexter the parameter is no longer available on the documentation.

Comment: @BoygeniusDexter it does not seem to work. Do you have an example or instructions?

Comment: has there been any traction on this? or has instagram just completely disallowed it now?

Comment: Any updates? Does it work now?

Answer (score 0):

Just the record observable result.

The key `com.instagram.sharedSticker.contentURL` needs the `special-appID`.

I did capture `UIPasteboard.general.items` which passing to Instagram. Even use the `special-appID`, Instagram uses the queryItems from URL to open the APP(special-appID).