# How to set an Instagram story like spotify In Android?(I want to share image with app url as story)

Tags: android, instagram, instagram-api, android-implicit-intent, instagram-story

I want to share an Image with my app link as an Instagram story when the user clicks on that link it's should redirect to my app. from Spotify app it's possible but I'm not able to do this. from the below code I can show the only image but I need to show an image with URL

```
     Uri backgroundAssetUri = Uri.parse(file);
 // Instantiate implicit intent with ADD_TO_STORY action and background asset
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.instagram.share.ADD_TO_STORY");
    intent.setDataAndType(backgroundAssetUri, MEDIA_TYPE_JPEG);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
 // Instantiate activity and verify it will resolve implicit intent
    Activity activity = getActivity();
  if (activity.getPackageManager().resolveActivity(intent, 0) != null) {
   activity.startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }
```

Comment: Did you find a solution on how to implement this?

Comment: See if this answer helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65715184/9453623

Comment: no @SergiMascaró

Comment: @saiandroid I believe you need to be some kind of registered partner with instagram to be able to have this attribution URL. You could try reaching out to them.