# How to embed deep link into app while sharing to Instagram Story similar to Spotify

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

[Play on Spotify](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcIkK.png)

How do I include a deep link to open my own app while sharing some content to Instagram story? I tried searching through the docs but the only relevant piece of code I could find was including the applicationId in the URI scheme but it did not work.

The URI scheme mentioned in the docs is `"instagram-stories://share?source_application=appId"` where the appId refers to the Facebook App ID but after sharing no deep link is shown

Answer (score 0):

I made a little research. Instagram, presented this feature in 2018, but right now it's not available anymore for everyone. I tried to do that by adding `com.instagram.sharedSticker.contentURL` to pasteboard (this was mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44283082/url-scheme-to-post-to-instagram-stories#comment125855691_52898962)), but it didn't work. Some people mentioned on Stackoverflow around 2021 that this feature had been disabled. However, some big apps like Spotify, Apple Music and other Meta apps can still do that. Here are some links where it was mentioned: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65627605/sharing-instagram-stories-with-open-app-link), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44283082/url-scheme-to-post-to-instagram-stories#comment125855691_52898962)