# Is it possible to add app link to instagram story sticker while using Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook, instagram, instagram-story

Hey we are trying to develop share to insta story functionality, managed to share background and the sticker, but wondering is it possible to make sticker clickable so on click it would open deep link or url? Can not find anything on documentation, [on swift it seems possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65627605/sharing-instagram-stories-with-open-app-link)